# Django timezone.now().time displays incorrect time zone

Tags: python, django, django-views

The subject is the simplest way that I can break down the problem that I am getting.

I'm using Django 2.1

*settings.py*

```
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'
TIME_ZONE = 'America/New_York'
USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True
USE_TZ = True
```

*views.py*

```
message = timezone.now().time
message2 = timezone.now
```

The above code is the fastest way to show the problem that I have. When I print 'message' I'm given a time different than what I get from 'message2' although they are both pulling the same value.

My model saves a datetimefield using the auto_now_add feature.

models.py

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    date_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True)
```

When I display the field in HTML as

```
{{ comment.date_time }}
```

the correct date and time appears. However when I use my own formatting and break up the code as

```
{{ comment.date_time.date }}: {{ comment.date_time.time }}
```

then I cannot get the time to display in the correct timezone. I've tried the following alterations all to no avail.

```
{% load tz %}

{% localtime on %}
{{ comment.date_time.time }}
{% endlocaltime %}

{{ comment.date_time.time|localtime }}
{{ comment.date_time.time|timezone:"America/New_York" }}
```

Does anyone know of a way to address this?

Comment: You can use `python manage.py shell` for quick tests instead of having to create and instantiate models.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

pass `timezone.now()` to `timezone.localtime`

```
from django.utils import timezone
timezone.localtime(timezone.now())
```

More info [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/timezones/#usage).

Comment: When using
 
    'from django.utils import timezone'
    'timezone.localtime(timezone.now().time)'

I get the following error 

    'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute "utcoffset"'

My issue is specific to displaying 'timezone.now().time' as its correct value as it shows in 'timezone.now'

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're using trying to use `time` objects instead of `datetime` objects. The `localtime` and `timezone` template tags and filters are expecting `datetime` objects.

If you want a custom format in the template, use the [`date`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#date) filter. If for whatever reason that can't give you the format you want, you will need to do the conversion yourself in the view rather than relying on the template, e.g.:

```
from django.utils.timezone import localtime

def view():
    local = localtime(comment.date_time)
    date_string = str(local.date())  # or whatever custom format you want
    time_string = str(local.time())  # or whatever custom format you want
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from django.utils import timezone
timezone.localtime(timezone.now())
```

Also, in the *settings.py* you must change:

```
TIME_ZONE = 'America/New_York'
```

A list of the time zone database names can be found on: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones